# Java with Ant: Error when connect SQL Server

Tags: java

I have a test project to connect SQL Server but I have an exception

**MY code:**

```
package service;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class DBconnect { //Kết nối
    private static final String USERNAME = "sa";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "123456a@";
    private static final String SERVER = "localhost";
    private static final String PORT = "1433";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TestConnect";
    private static final boolean USING_SSL = false;
    private static String CONNECT_STRING;
   
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
           
            StringBuilder connectStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            connectStringBuilder.append("jdbc:sqlserver://")
                    .append(SERVER).append(":").append(PORT).append(";")
                    .append("databaseName=").append(DATABASE_NAME).append(";")
                    .append("user=").append(USERNAME).append(";")
                    .append("password=").append(PASSWORD).append(";")
                    ;
            if (USING_SSL) {
                connectStringBuilder.append("encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;");
            }
            CONNECT_STRING = connectStringBuilder.toString();
            System.out.println("Connect String có dạng: " + CONNECT_STRING);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBconnect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
   
    public static Connection getConnection()  {
         try {
             return DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECT_STRING);
         } catch (SQLException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
             Logger.getLogger(DBconnect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             return null;
         }
    }
   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Connection conn = getConnection();
        DatabaseMetaData dbmt = conn.getMetaData();
        System.out.println(dbmt.getDriverName());
        System.out.println(dbmt.getDatabaseProductName());
        System.out.println(dbmt.getDatabaseProductVersion());
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4098)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3160)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:43)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3123)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1981)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1628)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1459)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:773)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1168)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:683)
at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:253)
at service.DBconnect.getConnection(DBconnect.java:40)
at service.DBconnect.main(DBconnect.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 15 more

How can i fix it?

Comment: NB: The linked-to answer is the first hit when you search the web for javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter - search the web before putting in the effort of typing up a question, saves you a lot of time :)